# Updating Json Array in LogicApp

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I am trying to update some JSON in a logic app.  Here is my JSON.

```html
{
  "headers": [
    {
      "count": 0,
      "lookup": "PSI"
    },
    {
      "count": 0,
      "lookup": "Clean"
    }
  ]
}
```

In a for each loop, I am trying to update the property `count` of a specific header array element.

Here is the setproperty I am doing.

`@setproperty(variables('colObj'), 'headers', setproperty(items('For_each'), 'count', 1))`

Currently, the setproperty only returns one element of the array and not the entire array.

I need the set property to return all elements of the headers array and to update the count property for the current foreach item.

Does anyone know how to do this in a logic app?

Comment: Any process? Could get the output with my way?

Answer (score 4):

Actually, we already know to set the child property in a child object, use a nested `setProperty()` call instead. And the `items('For_each')` is not quiet the child part of json data, it's like `variables('colObj')['headers'][0]`. And if you try to add one more nested `setProperty()`, it will say the array is not a object then your way will only get one child array object.

So if you want to get the complete json object you will have to add some actions to implement. Maybe you could refer to my flow.

I use a Parse_json to set the json data it should be your `variables('colObj')`,  one null object variable , one array variable.

[image]

In the For_each set the result object with `setProperty(body('Parse_JSON'),'headers',setProperty(items('For_each'),'count',34))` then append it to the array. After the For_each action init a new object to get the object you want and set it with `setProperty(body('Parse_JSON'),'headers',variables('middle'))`.

[image]

And this is the run details.

[image]

[image]